# While generating Bearer token getting "This resource must only be accessed over HTTPS. It was incorrectly accessed using HTTP"

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, restful-authentication, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-rest-data-services

We have http server for our dev / test environments. Both schemas are on same servers with different port numbers. Recently we have created few REST APIs. We get expected result from DEV environment.

On test environment, if roles and privilege are not applied it works. I mean I can successfully use API.

But once applied, I'm getting below mentioned error while genrating token on Postman.

`"Error-Reason: error="URL"; error_description*=UTF-8''This%20resource%20must%20only%20be%20accessed%20over%20HTTPS.%20It%20was%20incorrectly%20accessed%20using%20HTTP"`

For start I checked,

- There is no internal firewall blockings applied.
- `security.verifySSL` is set False
- `Authorization Required for Metadata Access` is set to Yes

Can help, what else I shall need to check?

Comment: Sorry, after ORDS restart it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the verifySSL setting is what controls this.

[https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-rest-enabled-sql#:~:text=By%20default%20the%20functionality%20is%20only%20available%20over,over%20HTTPS.%20It%20was%20incorrectly%20accessed%20using%20HTTP%22](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-rest-enabled-sql#:%7E:text=By%20default%20the%20functionality%20is%20only%20available%20over,over%20HTTPS.%20It%20was%20incorrectly%20accessed%20using%20HTTP%22).

Have you restarted ORDS to ensure the setting is taking effect?

Comment: Yes, DBA has restarted the ORDS. In fact I've asked to do it today as well.